# How to access mulesoft application metrics using JMX

Tags: spring-boot, mule, jmx, spring-jmx

I want to expose some custom application metrics like how many records processed to JMX in mulesoft flow.
My application is spring boot application.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Thanks & Regards,
Vikas Gite

Comment: just to make clear: you want your spring boot application to access mbeans, which are deployed inside a mule instance or vice versa?

Answer (score 2):

Using the Default JMX Support Agent
You can configure several JMX agents simultaneously using the  element. When set, this element registers the following agents:

1. List item
2. JMX agent
3. RMI registry agent (if necessary) on rmi://localhost:1099
4. Remote JMX access on service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/server
5. (Optional) Log4J JMX agent, which exposes the configuration of the Log4J instance used by Mule for JMX management
6. JMX notification agent used to receive server notifications using JMX notifications
7. (Optional) MX4J adapter, which provides web-based JMX management, statistics, and configuration viewing of a Mule instance

Also you can try below which can directly be configured under the MULE's wrapper.conf (under $MULE_HOME/conf/wrapper.conf) to enable JMX connectivity so that we can use tools like JMC (Java Mission Control), VisualVM, JConsole to pull the JMX attribute values from the Mule Server and the deployed applications -

```
wrapper.java.additional.<n>=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
wrapper.java.additional.<n>=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999 
wrapper.java.additional.<n>=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
wrapper.java.additional.<n>=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false 
wrapper.java.additional.<n>=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
wrapper.java.additional.<n>=-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<localhost ip> 
wrapper.java.additional.<n>=-Djava.rmi.activation.port=9998
```

Here  should be removed with the next incremental value of the java wrapper value and  will be the ip of the the Mule runtime host/server

I hope you are looking for this, if not then please post further queries or clarity so that i will help you out.